# Replace multiple words in list

Tags: python, regex, list, nltk

I have read a corpus using

```
file_directory = 'path'
my_corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(file_directory,'.*',encoding='latin1')
```

I perform preprocessing

```
    totalwords = my_corpus.words()
    docs = [my_corpus.words(f) for f in fids]
    docs2 = [[w.lower()for w in doc]for doc in docs]
    docs3 = [[w for w in doc if re.search('^[a-z]+$',w)]for doc in docs2]
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop_list = stopwords.words('english')
    docs4 = [[w for w in doc if w not in stop_list]for doc in docs3]
    wordscount = [w for doc in docs4 for w in doc]
    fd_dist_total = nltk.FreqDist(wordscount)
    print(fd_dist_total.most_common(common_words))
```

Output Received is

```
words = [('ubs', 131), ('pacific', 130), ('us', 121), ('credit', 113), ('aum', 108), ('suisse', 102), ('asia', 98), ('arm', 95)]
```

I would like to know if it is possible to replace 102 values of 'suisse' with 'credit-suisse'. Similarly replace 'asia' with 'asia-pacific'

Expected output --

```
words = [('credit-suisse', 102), ('credit', 11) , ('pacific', 32), ('asia-pacific', 98)]
```

I tried using

```
wordscount1 = [w.replace('asia','asia-pacific').replace('suisse', 'credit-suisse') for w in wordscount]
```

However i run into obvious errors.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Why is `credit-suisse` assigned `102` rather than `113` or `113 + 102`?

Comment: And why your received output is very different with your expected output, specially the values!!!

Comment: words = [('ubs', 131), ('pacific', 130), ('us', 121), ('credit', 113), ('aum', 108), ('suisse', 102), ('asia', 98), ('arm', 95)]. Just an example @Kasra. I would like all suisse replaced by 'credit-suisse'. How to ensure that the remaining 11 (113-102) 'credit' are in the output as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather underspecified as we don't know how to ensure that, for example, `count('suisse') >= count('credit')`. Particularly, you want to:

- replace 'suisse' by 'credit-suisse', keeping in credit (**first** term) `credit minus suisse`
- but, in the same time, you want to replace 'asia' by 'asia-pacific', keeping in pacific (**second** term) `pacific minus asia` (the opposite of the first case)

You definitively have to clarify that requirement. Maybe are your replacement terms sorted somehow? Anyway, as a starting point:

```
words = [('ubs', 131), ('pacific', 130), ('us', 121), 
         ('credit', 113), ('aum', 108), ('suisse', 102), 
         ('asia', 98), ('arm', 95)]

d = dict(words)

for terms in (('credit', 'suisse'), ('asia', 'pacific')):
    v1 = d.get(terms[1])
    if v1:
        d['-'.join(terms)] = v1
        v0 = d.get(terms[0],0)
        d[terms[0]] = v0-v1 # how to handle zero or negative values here ?
                            # it is unclear if it should be v1-v0 or v0-v1
                            # or even abs(v0-v1) 


from pprint import pprint

pprint(d)
pprint(d.items())
```

Producing:

```
sh$ python3 p.py
{'arm': 95,
 'asia': -32,    # <- notice that value
 'asia-pacific': 130,
 'aum': 108,
 'credit': 11,   # <- and this one
 'credit-suisse': 102,
 'pacific': 130,
 'suisse': 102,
 'ubs': 131,
 'us': 121}
dict_items([('us', 121), ('suisse', 102), ('aum', 108), ('arm', 95),
            ('asia-pacific', 130), ('ubs', 131), ('asia', -32),
            ('credit', 11), ('credit-suisse', 102), ('pacific', 130)])
```

Comment: How to ensure that ('credit', 11), ('credit-suisse', 102)? Similarly for 'asia-pacific'.

Comment: @RohanManek I've updated in depth my answer to show you how to process your list. Please note you will have to adapt that example to your particular case as some needs are not clearly specified. For now, I let you experiment with that.